# How to not page cache a route after a forward('defaultNoRoute')?

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I use a module which create a route with a non cacheable block in his layout. The page is not cached, like described in http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html

But on some conditions the module made a forward('defaultNoRoute'), then the cms 404 page layout is loaded and the page cached, then every next request gets the 404 cached page !!

try to add this before the forward

```
$page = $this->pageFactory->create();
//We are using HTTP headers to control various page caches (varnish, fastly, built-in php cache)
$page->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0', true);
```

but it load the entire layout before forward, it can cause some troubles, i don't find it very clean ...

Is there any other suggestion to avoid page cache 404 forward ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up to create a plugin on the isCacheable() method of Magento\Framework\View\Layout

In this plugin i check a variable in the registry i setup just before the forward to defaultNoRoute

Sounds more clean to me.